# Functionality of SinusoidalPattern_create() in python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to build a structured light 3D scanner with opencv in python, but fail already trying to create sinusoidal patterns. Firstly, I succesfully installed opencv:

```
print(cv2.__version__)
>>3.4.3
```

Furthermore, the structured light api seams to be succesfully installed:

```
print(dir(cv2.structured_light))
>>['DECODE_3D_UNDERWORLD', 'FAPS', 'FTP', 'GrayCodePattern_create', 'PSP', 'SinusoidalPattern_create', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

But the call for the creation of sinusoidal patterns is nowhere really documented:

```
cv2.structured_light.SinusoidalPattern_create()
>> <structured_light_SinusoidalPattern 00000155FFFAECD0>
```

At this point, I don't know how to get sinusoidal pattern to display or plot nor how to put the possible paramters (resolution, phase shift etc.) into the SinusoidalPattern_create() function.

Can anyone kindly provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. You can try to use the [C++ tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d0/de8/tutorial_capture_sinusoidal_pattern.html) of this class of OpenCV. The functions are almost the same in python... and at least is a place to start

Comment: Thank you for your response. Thank you also for the link to the C++ tutorial. Unfortunately, the syntax-related differences between C++ and Python don't improve my understanding of the structure of the input which is required by 'cv2.structured_light.SinusoidalPattern_create()'.